# Sharepoint Dashboard Designer 2010 Filters and All Total Values

Tags: filter

I have an Analytic Grid that has a column with values (for example) {Cat, Dog, Other}. Each of those items have a number associated with them. For example, cat is 10, dog is 10, and other is 2.

In my grid, I only want the Cat and Dog columns to show. So I use the drop down in Dashboard Designer called Select Members. I Choose Cat and Dog. I also want the total of those values in my grid, so I use the checkbox All.

When the grid is displayed. It shows the All field as well, but it lists the value as 22 not the 20 I was expecting.

Is there a way to hide the unselected member values from the all total calculation? (So that the All field would say 20?)

Another way to put this is the example where you can "not include" hidden data in MS Excel Pivot tables.